# AppLovin Ad Network Apple Store Submission SDK Error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, applovin

I have implemented AppLovin ad network within my game and its working properly in my iOS build so I have decided to submit it to Apple Store.

During the submission process, I got this error and I can't able to upload my game build at Apple Store.

[image]

Please share your suggestion regarding this error so I can make a correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apple Store submission, libAppLovinSdk.a file showing the above error.
So I have removed that file from xCode project in inserted AppLovinSDK.framework file that I can download from following the page of a website.

[image]

Then after running the game build on iPhone, everything running properly so I started uploading the build to Apple Store and I got success in that.

So you don't require to use the library for iOS platform that you get with Unity package. Use framework file for Ads SDK within xCode project.

I hope this information becomes useful to others.